# Minimal number of generators for a f.g module over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R =  \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $M$ be a finitely generated torsion free $R$-module with rank $n$, and let $\mu ( M)$ denote the minimal number of generators of $M$. For each prime ideal $P \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$, let $\mu_P ( M)$ denote the dimension of $M_P / P M_P$ as a vector space over $R_P / PR_P$.  Note that $\mu_P ( M)$ is also the minimal number of generators for $M_P$ over $R_P$ by Nakayama's lemma.

The Forster-Swan Theorem says that
$$\mu ( M ) \leq \mathrm{max}_P \{  \mu_P (M) + \mathrm{Krull\, dim \,\, } R / P \}. $$

The prime ideals of $R$ have been classified and come in 3 flavors:

1. $(0)$.
2. $(f)$ for an irreducible polynomial with relatively prime coefficients or a prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$.
3. $(p, f)$ where $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ is prime and $f$ is irreducible mod $ p $.

Can one use this nice prime ideal structure and the Forster-Swan theorem to bound $\mu ( M)$ in terms of $n$?

Note that the problem is easy when $M$ is projective, since f.g. projective modules over $R$ are free by the Quillen-Suslin theorem.